# Detect if any <tr> in a table has a given display property with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, slidetoggle, tablerow

When a user do a search, each table row (`tr`) that does not match is set to `display: none;`.
Is there a way to detect when all rows in the table is set to `display: none;` using jQuery? *(meaning there was no match)*

Also, detect if there's any table rows that either has no style at all, or has the `display`-property set to `table-row`? *(meaning there's at least one match)*

What I'm trying to accomplish is an automated way to show or hide a form (`#RequestRecipe`) where the user can submit a request for what they just searched for.

As of now, I have a button the user can click to show the form. But an automated way would give a better ux..

```
<table class="quicksearch striped" id="recipes">
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>  /*  state of <tr> when the page is loaded / is a match (visable)  */
        <tr style="display:none"></tr>  /*  not a match (hidden)  */
        <tr style="display:table-row;"></tr>  /*  is a match after it has been hidden due to a no match from a search (visable)  */
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When using quicksearch, the plugin adds and changes the display property according to if the searchfield is a match to the contents in the `<tr>`.

I don't really have any code for the show/hide other than the code to actually show/hide the form.

```
$(function(){
    $('#toggle_RequestRecipe').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#RequestRecipe').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us your code. It sounds like you want to iterate over the `tr`'s twice... once to show results, and once to check results. Same for the `table-row`.. You only need to iterate once....

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a `:visible` pseudo selector for that.

> https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Make sure to read the documentation to know what jQuery considers visible.

```js
console.log($('#table1 tr:visible').length);

console.log($('#table2 tr:visible').length);

console.log($('#table3 tr:visible').length);
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr hidden>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="visibility: hidden">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
  <tr hidden>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table3">
  <tr hidden>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```